# Is association bonus reputation points taken in account for >= 200 reputation badges?

Tags: support, badges, linked-accounts, daily-reputation-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Yesterday I registered in Meta Stack Overflow and I got the +100 association bonus. In SO, I got more than 200 reputation points and I didn't obtained `Mortarboard` badge:

> Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day

Are this 100 points not taken in account in daily reputation for >= 200 daily reputation badges?

**Edit:**

If I check https://stackoverflow.com/reputation I can see at the end:

> earned at least 200 reputation on 1 days

But still no `Mortarboard` badge awarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Badge FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/187824) for Mortarboard:

> - **Reputation points earned for associating accounts** or for accepting other users' answers to your own questions do **not** count for the badge.

So you did not earn badge because you actually earned [137 (237-100) reputation yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/users/621264/atxe?tab=reputation).